# Python inFile loops not getting every item in the file

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write a program that reads from a list a series of names and numbers like this:

```
5
Jim
79 84 82
Bob
32 12 47
Kelly
90 86 93
Courtney
80 99 89
Chad
89 78 91
```

The format for the numbers is:

```
<Assignment score>   <Quiz Score>   <Exam Score>
```

And the multipliers for each are:

```
.3 .1 .6
```

Currently I have this:

```
def main():
    inFile = open("input.txt","r")

    numVals = int(inFile.readline())
    for i in range(numVals):
        name = inFile.readline()


    numbers = inFile.readline().split()
    for n in range(len(numbers)):
        numbers[n] = float(int(numbers[n]))

    avg = float(numbers[0]* .3 + numbers[1]* .1 + numbers[2]* .6)
    print(name, "'s Score is",avg,"%.")

    inFile.close()

main()
```

My output should look like this:

```
Jim’s score is <avg>.
Bob’s score is <avg>.
Kelly’s score is <avg>.
Courtney’s score is <avg>.
Chad’s score is <avg>.
```

But instead, I get this:

```
Kelly
 's Score is <avg> %.
```

Any ideas on how to get the print to get every name in the file and every line of numbers in the file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is much better put than your [originally deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905694/in-python-how-do-i-make-each-line-in-a-file-a-separate-list) - notice how much more quickly it's getting responses (and not downvote or close votes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to strip the trailing newlines from the result of readline.

Maybe like this:

```
weights = [.3, .1, .6]
with open ('file2.txt') as f:
    count = int (f.readline ().strip () )
    for i in range (count):
        name = f.readline ().strip ()
        score = sum (w * s for w,s in zip (weights, (int (x) for x in f.readline ().strip ().split () ) ) )
        print ('{}\'s Score is {} %.'.format (name, score) )
```

Comment: How do I go about doing that? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: If I wanted to have the print statement go to 2 decimal places, where does the %.2f% go?

Comment: `(:.2f}` or something like that

Comment: @Drieke -- have a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: @Hyperboreus -- Apparently.  Do you always leave whitespace between your function/method names and their respective argument lists?  I've *never* seen that before.

Comment: This comes from way back. I think it comes from mathematics and/or early functional languages. If you write `3 * (2 + 4) / (3 + 8)`, then `3 * f (2 + 4) / g (3 + 8)` comes naturally. But to be honest, I just find it easier to read (for me personally). De gustibus non est disputandum...

Comment: Got it, its: `print('{}\'s Score is {:.2f} %.'.format (name, score) )`

Answer (score 0):

So you have 5 records, each with 2 lines.  The first task is to ingest that information properly.  You can get a line via `fin.readline()` or via `next(fileobject)` which will work on python3.x as well.

```
weights = ( 0.3, 0.1, 0.3 )
with open('datafile') as fin: #open file for reading
    n = int(next(fin)) #read the first line and figure out how many people there will be
    for _ in range(n): #Loop over the records, 2 at a time:
        name = next(fin).strip() #read the name, strip off the whitespace.
        grades = [float(x) for x in next(fin).split()] #read the grades, make then floats
        total = sum( w*g for w,g in zip(weights,grades) )
        print name, total
```

This really isn't too much different than what you have so far:

```
def main():
    inFile = open("input.txt","r")

    numVals = int(inFile.readline())
    for i in range(numVals):
        name = inFile.readline() #add a .strip() here
        #grades = [float(x) for x in inFile.readline().strip()]
        #do the rest of the processing for a single person here 
        #since you have all their info.  If you wait, you'll replace
        #the info you currently have with the info for the next person
        #You'll continue to do that until the last person -- meaning
        #that at the end of the day, you'll only have the info for the
        #last person.
```